# Hover style sticking in IE7

Tags: css

I am having an issue with my CSS that only occurs in IE7 and am hoping someone else has encountered this before.  Basically we have a customer grid design where the cells highlight when hovered over.  This works great, however in IE7 the highlighting sticks, you hove over the cell then leave the cell and the highlighting is still there.

Here is the css I am using for the cell

```
.cell input:hover
{
    background-color: #54B5FF;
}
```

Thanks!

Edit:Parent

```
.cell input
{
border:none;
background:transparent;
padding:11px 6px;
width:35px;
height:16px;
line-height:16px;
text-align:right;
background-color:transparent;
border-radius:0;-moz-border-radius:0;-webkit-border-radius:0;
 }
```

edit:Found the fix!

I found a fix I thought I'd share with anyone else encountering this bug in the future.  Apparently in IE7 only certain style changes cause a situation called hasLayout which apparently causes it to re-render properly.  In my case I changed the code to

```
.cell input:hover
{
position: static;
background-color: #D7ECFF;
}
```

This didn't change anything, but it did cause IE7 to properly render it!

Comment: Wait... IE7 supports hover on inputs?  You're not using javascript at all?

Comment: Yep, and see my edit for the solution

Comment: After a bit of digging, I see that IE7 does indeed support the :hover pseudo-class when used with a strict doctype.  The more you know.

Answer (score 0):

Set a default.

Try:

```
.cell input {
    background-color: #fff; /* or whatever you want it to be... */
}

.cell input:hover
{
    background-color: #54B5FF;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have posted the parent
    `.cell input
    {
 border:none;
 background:transparent;
 padding:11px 6px;
 width:35px;
 height:16px;
 line-height:16px;
 text-align:right;
 background-color:transparent;
 border-radius:0;-moz-border-radius:0;-webkit-border-radius:0;
    }`